# XSL select where element has two attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath

How do I select elements that have two attributes?

I can do

```
@name | @area
```

which is "name or area", but how do I do "name **and** area"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, don't use `@name | @area` - it's not 'or', it's a join which happens to work incidentally.

For 'or', do `foo[@name or @area]`.
For 'and', do `foo[@name and @area]`.

Comment: I might call using "@name | @area" that way roundabout, but not incidental. Effectively, it says "does this expression return any results?" The answer of course is yes if either or both attributes are present. It's a reasonable alternative for expressing the same condition.

Answer (score 4):

XPath does provide you with an `and` operator which can be used to evaluate multiple conditions using predicates:

Possibles:

```
//MyElement[@name][@area]
//MyElement[@name and @area]
```

Comment: I don't, but only out of habit. Is there a valid reason not to?

Comment: Well, because it's ugly? I can't think of a more valid reason, frankly :)

Comment: You have a sense of humour! :P

Comment: Heh, I often prefer multiple predicates over explicit logical operators ("and"). I suppose it's a matter of taste. Depending on how complex the pattern or expression is, I'll also break it up into multiple lines and align one predicate above the next one.

Comment: I wouldn't use the first because it will evaluate the first condition, select the  nodes validating that condition and then apply second condition. No harm done here but look : [position()=1][position()=1] --OR-- [position()=1 and position()=1]
First condition select the second node, second condition select the first node.